# Vuex module state has default values in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

I am using **`Vue3`** with **`vuex`** and **`vue-router`**. I started from beginning, just created **`Vue3`** app.
My idea is to create some kind of authentication. Idea is if the user logs in successfully, in response I will get token, and I will set cookie with this token. Then in app I will check if the token is set I will get user data and add them to the store, if token is not set, some pages should unavailable because user is not authenticated. Plan is to add router guard in router/index.js. When I want to use something from the store, values are default and I don't know where I should fetch data in the app that I have updated values after fetching?

In main js file I am fetching user data.
**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

store.dispatch('users/getUser')

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

**users.js** is vuex module where I have getUser action. When I do console log here, I am getting all data and this is fine.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export const users = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: {
      id: null,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null
    }
  },

  getters: {
    getFirstName: (state) => state.user.firstName
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE_USER_FIRST_NAME: (state, newValue) => { state.user.firstName = newValue }
  },

  actions: {
    async getUser ({ commit, state }) {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api2/getUser.php', {
        token: 'aa8527d2184aa9396cffd282af410dc1b02c4427d703b90cf72e7f80881e9f01eb8ddd656c49d76680ad59fc30f3a3b565654f174cfe17a5341a30bd5f930e53'
      }).then((response) => {
        commit('UPDATE_USER_FIRST_NAME', response.data.firstName)
        console.log('response:', response.data)
      })
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
}
```

When I do console log here value is null (default value).
**router/index.js**

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import store from '../store'

console.log(store.getters['users/getFirstName'])

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/categories',
    name: 'Categories',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Categories.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

In store folder I have modules folder and there for now just users.js module.
**store/index.js**

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { users } from './modules/users'

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    users
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you share your ./store?

Comment: I added store. You can see, there is only imported module users.js.

Comment: I am not sure about this one. But, my current setup contains this `export const store = createStore({`.

Comment: So you have something like I have in users.js ?

Answer (score 0):

`main.js`

You will need to wait for the dispatch to resolve.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App)

store.dispatch('users/getUser')
 .then(() => {
  app.use(store).use(router).mount('#app');
});
```

Or wrap the dispatch in an `async` function. And `await` the dispatch itself.

Comment: For both cases I got null if I do console log inside router/index.js

Comment: Does anyone know what the problem is? Please help :/